# Nested if statement that won't work

Tags: php, forms

I cannot figure out what's wrong. My form serves two purposes. Email basic data, or if the visitor wants a catalog, to display additional fields for more data.

Somehow the validation code for the additional fields -- address, city, state, zip -- is preventing the code to finish and send an email. The validation for each field works fine, but when the checkbox is checked, no mail is sent. Without it checked, it works, and if I remove that part it works.

I have narrowed it down, but cannot figure it out. Any assistance is appreciated.

The sanitize() function is in an included helper.php file.

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'submit_contact_info') {

    $name = sanitize($_POST['name']);
    $email = sanitize($_POST['email']);
    $telephone = sanitize($_POST['telephone']);
    $form_message = sanitize($_POST['message']);
    $address = sanitize($_POST['address']);
    $city = sanitize($_POST['city']);
    $state = sanitize($_POST['state']);
    $zip = sanitize($_POST['zip']);

    // Store visitor name in SESSION variable for use @thankyou
        $_SESSION['name'] = $name;  

    // Check if fields have input
    if(empty($name))
    {
        $errMsg['name'] = '*Please enter your name.';
    }
    elseif(empty($email))
    {
        $errMsg['email'] = '*Please enter your email address.';
    }
    elseif(empty($telephone)) 
    {
        $errMsg['telephone'] = '*Please enter your telephone number.';
    }   
        elseif (isset($_POST['catalog_yes'])){
            // Check if mailing  fields have input
            if(empty($address))
            {
                $errMsg['address'] = 'Please enter your address.';
            }
            elseif(empty($city))
            {
                $errMsg['city'] = 'Please enter your city.';
            }
            elseif(empty($state))
            {
                $errMsg['state'] = 'Please enter your state.';
            }
            elseif(empty($zip))
            {
                $errMsg['zip'] = 'Please enter your zip code.';
            }
        } 
        else {        
        // Prepare message for e-mail; set e-mail recipient  
        $jim_gmail = 'jim@gmail.com';

        $to = $jim_gmail;
        $subject = 'Web site inquiry';
        $from = $email;
        $message = '
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
        <h2>Web site message via Contact Form</h2>
        <p>Name: ' . $name . '<br>
           Email: ' . $email . '<br>
           Telephone: ' . $telephone . '<br>
           Message: ' . $form_message . '<br>
           Adress: ' . $address . '<br>
           City: ' . $city . '<br>
           State: ' . $state . '<br>    
           Zip Code: ' . $zip . '<br>    
        </body>
        </html>
        '; // end of message
        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";      // code to send HTML on UNIX
        $headers .= 'Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        // Additional headers
        $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

        // Send message using mail() function 
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        header('Location: thankyou.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the name of that check box. Is it `catalog_yes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put the condition

```
elseif (isset($_POST['catalog_yes'])){

} else {
  //The final code, which will never run if $_POST['catalog_yes'] is set
}
```

So you need to move the codes you are putting under final ELSE outside of the else if conditions. There can be only one condition like this :

```
if(!count($errMsg)) {
   // Prepare message for e-mail; set e-mail recipient  
    $jim_gmail = 'jim@gmail.com';

    $to = $jim_gmail;
    $subject = 'Web site inquiry';
    $from = $email;
    $message = '
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <h2>Web site message via Contact Form</h2>
    <p>Name: ' . $name . '<br>
       Email: ' . $email . '<br>
       Telephone: ' . $telephone . '<br>
       Message: ' . $form_message . '<br>
       Adress: ' . $address . '<br>
       City: ' . $city . '<br>
       State: ' . $state . '<br>    
       Zip Code: ' . $zip . '<br>    
    </body>
    </html>
    '; // end of message
    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";      // code to send HTML on UNIX
    $headers .= 'Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

    // Send message using mail() function 
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    header('Location: thankyou.php');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: @Tareq. Thank you! I failed to see that $_POST['catalog_yes'] being set would prohibit the final code from executing. I was focused on it being set so the input could be checked.  Great work! I really appreciate you taking the time to look at this. The pain and suffering is worth it when I learn something. Thanks again!